# Windows Admin Center: Cannot connect to local Windows 10 system in Workgroup

Tags: wac

I've installed Windows Admin Center with default settings and managed to get into the dashboard at "localhost:6516". But when I tried to click the hyperlink for the localhost to connect, I get the below error

> Connecting to remote server XXXX failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I've read through some guides the below guides and had added the below commands as suggested but to no avail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/support/troubleshooting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/deploy/prepare-environment

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1
Set-Item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value *
Enable-PSRemoting -force
winrm quickconfig
```

I've verified that my winRM service is "Running" and that trustedhosts shows value of "*".

My login to Windows 10 is via my gmail account. And when i click on "Manage as > Use my Windows account for this connection", I also get the above error.

I've tried adding the computer manually in WAC but doesn't work. I've also re-installed WAC several times.

What else could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you resolved this situation in the meantime?